# Practical beginners resource for building a dynamic OLS model

Tags: data-transformation, least-squares, model, diagnostic

I need to model the current account balance of a country. The regressors are the real effective exchange rate, the domestic GDP and the GDP of the world. I am using data for 30 years (in logs). It is non-stationary so I am running a dynamic OLS (DOLS) model. The problem is that when I do it, I get strange results such as wrong signs, absurd coefficients, serial correlation, heteroskedasticity, and R-squared in the range of 0.97-0.99 (which seems weird to me).

I assume there has to be some problem with my data and the way I specify my model, however, I do not know how to fix this. So I would like to ask the more experienced members for some quality resources on setting up your data and specifying your model.

Comment: Its called a spurious regression (http://davegiles.blogspot.fi/2012/05/more-about-spurious-regressions.html). The stocahstic trends in your data are dominating leading to such a high R2. Try to read up on unit roots (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root). 

You say yourself that the data is non-stationary. You'll need to difference the data or model it as an ECM. In the case of a time trend you'll need to de-trend the data.

Unless you have stationarity and weak dependence/mixing the LLN and CLT will not aply.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Dan! Since my data is non-stationary, I am running the DOLS model, which I believe should be suitable. But even if I do run the VECM, I still get wrong signs.

Comment: A DOLS? Does that mean a 1st differenced OLS or dynamic OLS? Please edit your question and show exactly what model you are running.

Comment: I am referring to a dynamic OLS

Comment: In the case of unit roots and/or time trends a DOLS is not enough. Your estimators will not be consistent. What you experience is a spurious regression. Again, if you want more help post the model you are using and/or regression output. Have you done a unit root test on your variables?